# What is the probability of guessing the position of three out of ten elements correctly?

Tags: probability

Let's say I draw ten numbers from 1 to 10 without replacement. My friend can say 10 numbers in a particular order. What is the probability of her:

- guessing exactly three positions correctly?
- guessing at least three positions correctly?

I was able to do it through simulation, but I'm interested in the probability theory behind it.

Thank you in advance
Roel

Comment: This is a generalization of a *derangement:* see the [Wikipedia article on rencontres numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers). See especially the line following "The proof is easy ... ".